# Redundant conditions of `if` statement

Tags: python

Are the conditions of my `if` statement redundant?

```
if 'a' in b and b['a']:
```

`'a'` is a dictionary

Comment: Write some code to test your hypothesis.

Comment: Try with `b = {'c':42}` then with `b = {'a':42}` then with `b = {'a':0}`

Comment: ```'a' in b``` as name says you are checking if there's any 'a' in list b. ```b['a']``` is a way of indexing which is an integer always so we can have ```if  'a' in b and b[i] == 'a'``` where ```i``` is an ```int```  which points to where 'a' is present in list and actually both conditions mean the same so you can have either ```if 'a' in b:``` or ```if b[i] == 'a'```

Comment: @AlexBlasco I am helping you. Your test program would be trivial and it would teach you a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming b is a dictionary, the condition isn't redundant. Quoting an example below

```
 b={'a':1,'b':1}
```

Here, both the conditions will be True as 1)'a' in b will mean if key 'a' is present  & 2) b['a'] means if the value at key 'a' is not None/0 which is true

```
 b={'a':None}
```

Here, the 1st condition will be true as key 'a' is present but the 2nd condition is false as the value at 'a' is None

Answer (score 1):

If `b` is an array of non-integers then `b['a']` won't work. 
`b['a']` is basically asking to access the 'a'th element of b list. 
If a is not an int it wont work.

Even if a is an integer then also b[a] is not the same as checking if element a in in list b.

If your requirement is to check if element a exists in list b,

```
if 'a' in b:
    some code
```

works just fine.

Comment: `b` could also be a dictionary, or literally any object that has a `__contains__` method & accepts strings as `item`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you'd like to achieve with b['a']. Could you show us more of your code? Is b a dictionary? If it is, then "if 'a' in b" is not correct, you should use b.keys(), if 'a' should be a key, b.values(), if 'a' should be a value, or b.items() if it could be both. And if it b['a'] should be an element of a dictionary, it should evaluate to either True or False in a boolean context. (For int or float, 0 evaluates to False whereas any other value evaluates to True. For strings, an empty string evaluates to False whereas any other value evaluates to True. For lists, tuples, dictionaries or sets, if it is empty, it'll evaluate to False, if it contains one or more items, it'll evaluate to True.)

If b is a string, then b['a'] has no meaning, it can neither evaluate to True nor False.